# Pandas, convert date from DDD MM/DD to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: python, pandas

In my Date column, I have the date in the following format: `Sat 11/16`. Is there any way to convert this column to `yyyy-mm-dd`? 
The expected output would be `2019-11-16`

Trying `d1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(d1['Date'].str.strip()+'/2019')`  but getting error on `ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', 'Averages/2019')`

here is my data set:

```
0     Mon 11/18
1     Sat 11/16
2     Wed 11/13
3     Mon 11/11
4     Sun 11/10
5      Fri 11/8
6      Wed 11/6
7      Sat 11/2
8      november
9     Wed 10/30
10    Mon 10/28
11    Sat 10/26
12      october
13     Averages
14       Totals
15    Fri 10/18
16    Sun 10/13
17    Thu 10/10
18     Tue 10/8
19       Boston
20           W1
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: What will be `YYYY` in your destination? Which year exactly. Or it won't matter which year! Jus a plce holder

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: This does not make sense, assuming month is november and year is 2016, which saturday of the month is this? There are 4 saturdays in a month.

Comment: year would be 2019, probably a static amount

Comment: What is your expected output date here? Can your reply to my comment, the date does not make any sense right now.

Comment: convert "Sat 11/16" to "2019-11-16"

Comment: Never assume about the year! You should really work to get your input data in a better format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `/2019` to the column and use `pd.to_datetime`. Doing extra `str.strip` before adding to clean up any white space

```
df['New_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.strip()+'/2019', errors='coerce')

Out[12]:
         Date   New_Date
0   Mon 11/18 2019-11-18
1   Sat 11/16 2019-11-16
2   Wed 11/13 2019-11-13
3   Mon 11/11 2019-11-11
4   Sun 11/10 2019-11-10
5    Fri 11/8 2019-11-08
6    Wed 11/6 2019-11-06
7    Sat 11/2 2019-11-02
8    november 2019-11-01
9   Wed 10/30 2019-10-30
10  Mon 10/28 2019-10-28
11  Sat 10/26 2019-10-26
12    october 2019-10-01
13   Averages        NaT
14     Totals        NaT
15  Fri 10/18 2019-10-18
16  Sun 10/13 2019-10-13
17  Thu 10/10 2019-10-10
18   Tue 10/8 2019-10-08
19     Boston        NaT
20         W1        NaT
```

Comment: Hey andy im getting an error on non date values, is there any workaround?

Comment: use `errors='coerce'` to set `NaT` (it is `NaN` version of `datetime`) for those rows. I edited the answer.